# Несколько маршрутов на одной карте

Tags: google-maps-api

У меня есть 5 страниц, имеющих id = "map", мне необходимо загрузить в них 5 одинаковых карт, но с разными маршрутами. Как это сделать?

```
   var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
var map;

function initialize() 
{
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var mapOptions = {
center: myLatLng,
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);   
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
title: 'Я тут!'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

}   
  initialize();

var start = myLatLng;
var end = arrMyLatLng[8];
var waypts = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

  waypts.push({
      location:arrMyLatLng[i],
      stopover:true
  });
}

var request = {
  origin: start,
  destination: end,
  waypoints: waypts,
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
 };
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  var route = response.routes[0];

}
});
```

Это наложение одного маршрута. Не пойму, где маршрут привязывается к карте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточняю - карта должна быть проинициализирована один раз, при загрузке страницы, к примеру, и спрятана в переменную в глобальной области видимости. 
объект `directionsDisplay` может формироваться сколько угодно раз и будет выведен на ту же карту без ее перезагрузки.
вывод маршрута производится в момент привязки объекта к карте.
вот кусок моего рабочего кода с маршрутами:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
    start = document.getElementById("routefrom"),
    end = document.getElementById("routeto"),
    marshrut=[],
    request = { origin:start.value, destination:end.value, travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING };

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
    document.getElementById("other").innerHTML+=start.value+' - '+end.value+': <b>'+myRoute.distance.text+'</b><br>';
  }
});

directionsDisplay.setMap(myMap.mapa); // инициализирована при старте
```

Comment: это же карту перерисовывает. А как маршрут прицепить? 
Обернул все в функцию. В качестве параметра передавал id селектора.

Comment: расширил ответ